# adding a background in monogame isn't working

Tags: c#, graphics, arguments, monogame

I just want to add a background image in my c# monogame main menu. I already have a main menu with buttons and a working game. Just the background is missing.
This is a part of my code:

```
public void LoadAssets()
{
    background = ScreenManager.Texture("background");
    [...] //unimportant stuff for this problem
}

 public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch= new SpriteBatch();
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 480), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    foreach (var button in mButtons) 
    { 
    button.Draw(ScreenManager.mSprites);
    }
}
```

I get the following error CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of "graphicsDevice" from "SpriteBatch.SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice).

I included the image in content. I don't know where is my error.
Thanks, for help!

Comment: read the docs .. there is no parameterless constructor for class `SpriteBatch`

Comment: yes, but I have no idea, which paramter i should add

Comment: I can't use GraphicsDevice.

Comment: Read the docs. This doesn't warrant a question on SO, it's extremely basic stuff. Look up some examples. Also what do you mean, you can't use GraphicsDevice ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you do NOT create a new SpriteBatch instance each draw call. That would be like 60 new instances per second (at 60fps)

Instead, you create it in your LoadContent() method and use it all the way in your Draw() 
 method:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    [...]
}
```

Second, GraphicsDevice is definetly available in your Draw-Call as long as you have not messed something up really bad ;)